# There is no [OperationContract] section in C# References

Tags: c#, web-services

Help me please with this problem:
Service Reference was added.
And after that C#-code with web service classes was created.

But is it ok when there is no **[OperationContract]** section in it ?
Also there is no implementation of Channel:
**retrieveConvergenceBidAwards_v2_DocAttachChannel**

Also i am not sure why is here "**SOA**" ?
[image]

In documentation working URL for Web Service looks like this:
https://ws.caiso.com/sst/cmri/RetrieveConvergenceBidAwards_CMRIv2_DocAttach_AP?wsdl

Write me please, what i missed in all of this ?

Here is the file: (it is too long for forum)
https://ru.files.fm/u/rtppnnuu

Comment: I am not sure how to add Reference-code to this Forum...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: Here it is:
https://ru.files.fm/u/rtppnnuu